# Concatenation of the 7th lower bits of n bytes

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I just wanted to know if there is any difference between these two expressions:

1 : `a = ( a | ( b&0x7F ) >> 7 );`

2 : `a = ( ( a << 8 ) | ( b&0x7F ) << 1 );`

I'm not only speaking about result, but also about efficiency (but the first one looks better).

The purpose is to concatenate the 7 lower bits of multiple bytes, and I was at first using number 2 like this:

```
while(thereIsByte)
{
  a = ( ( a << 8 ) | ( b&0x7F ) << i );
  ++i;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: where are the declarations of `a` and `b`?

Comment: Just as an aside, if you are doing this for GSM encoding purposes, the bits are not concatenated in "straight" order like this.

Comment: I'm doing it for EMV, but all I need is to fully support ASN.1. a and b are char.

Comment: How can any of these expressions "concatenate the 7 lower bits of multiple bytes"? I don't see any connection. In the last version, what is that shift `<< i` doing there? Why is `a` shifted by 8 bits??? You need to provide a better explanation of what you are trying to do, preferably with examples, because at this time there seems to be absolutely connection between the code and what you are saying.

Comment: `>>` has higher precedence than `|`, which means that in your first variant you are evaluating `(b & 0x7F) >> 7`, which is always zero. What is the point of that and how can you possibly say that it "looks better"??

Comment: Yep, this is why I need to move 'a' to the left and no 'b' to the right ! Thanks to you for trying to understand. @NetVipeC have understand what I wanted this is all good and his answer have been accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two expression don't do anything alike:

1. `a = ( a | ( b&0x7F ) >> 7 );`

**Explaining:**

```
a              = 0010001000100011
b              = 1000100010001100
0x7f           = 0000000001111111
b&0x7f         = 0000000000001100
(b&0x7f) >> 7  = 0000000000000000 (this is always 0), you are selecting the lowest 
                                   7 bits of 'b' and shifting right 7bit, discarding
                                   the selected bits).
(a | (b&0x7f) >> 7) always is equal to `a`
```

2. `a = ( ( a << 8 ) | ( b&0x7F ) << 1 );`

**Explaining:**

```
a              = 0010001000100011
b              = 1000100010001100
0x7f           = 0000000001111111
b&0x7f         = 0000000000001100
(b&0x7f) << 1  = 0000000000011000
(a << 8)       = 0010001100000000
(a << 8) | (b&0x7F) << 1 = 0010001100011000
```

In the second expression the result would have the 3 lowest bytes of `a` as the 3 highest bytes and the lowest byte of `b` without the highest bit, shifting 1 bit to the left. Would line `a = a * 256 + (b & 0x7f) * 2`

If you want to concatenate the lowest 7bits of `b` in `a` would be:

```
while (thereIsByte) {
    a = (a << 7) | (b & 0x7f);
    // read the next byte into `b`
}
```

Example in case of `sizeof(a)` = 4 bytes and you are concatenating four 7bits info, the result of the pseudo code would be:

```
a = uuuuzzzzzzzyyyyyyyxxxxxxxwwwwwww
```

Where the `z` are the 7 bits of the first byte readed, the `y` are the 7bits of the second and so on. The `u` are unused bits (contain the info in the lowest 4 bits of `a` at the beginning)

In this case the size of `a` need to be greater that the total bits you want to concatenate (eg: at least 32 bits if you want to concatenate four 7bits info).

If `a` and `b` are one byte of size won't be really much concatenating, you probably need a data structure like [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) where you can append bits multiple times and it grow accondinly.

Comment: What if a and b are only 1 byte ?

Comment: the the subexpression `(a << 8)` is equal to `0`, and you are only doing the selection of the lowest 7bits of `b` and shifting 1 to the left. What exactly you want to accomplish, concatenated in `a` the lowest 7bits of `b`?

Comment: I want to take the lowest 7bits of 'a' concatened to the lowest 7bits of 'b', concatened with the 7 lowest bits of the next byte (c ?) for n bytes

Comment: If they're only one byte, there nonetheless promoted to `int` before the shift (be aware that `unsigned char` usually gets promoted to `signed int`).

Comment: @MoKaT: What difference does it make? 1 byte or 10 bytes, subexpression `(b & 0x7F) >> 7` is always zero. It does not make any sense.

Comment: Okay, I've understood my mistake, thanks @NetVipeC. I wanted to use std::bitset, but the convertion from bitset to the value is not the best, I think I'm going to try boost. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are different. On MSVC2010 here is the disassembly when both a and b are chars.

```
a = ( a | ( b&0x7F ) >> 7 );
012713A6  movsx       eax,byte ptr [a]  
012713AA  movsx       ecx,byte ptr [b]  
012713AE  and         ecx,7Fh  
012713B1  sar         ecx,7  
012713B4  or          eax,ecx  
012713B6  mov         byte ptr [a],al  

a = ( ( a << 8 ) | ( b&0x7F ) << 1 );
012813A6  movsx       eax,byte ptr [a]  
012813AA  shl         eax,8  
012813AD  movsx       ecx,byte ptr [b]  
012813B1  and         ecx,7Fh  
012813B4  shl         ecx,1  
012813B6  or          eax,ecx  
012813B8  mov         byte ptr [a],al
```

Notice that the second method does two shift operations (for a total of 9 shifted bits, which each take a clock cycle) while the first does a single shift (only 7 bits) and read. Basically this is caused by the order of operations. The first method IS more optimized, however shifting is one of the computers most efficient operations and this difference is probably negligible for most applications.

Notice the compiler treated them as bytes, NOT signed ints.